# OpenGL obj loader in C

Tags: c, opengl

As a learning endeavor I'm trying to make an OpenGL(3.3+) program in C, but I've hit a snag on the model loader.
Everything I can find on the internet about loading obj files happens to involve C++ vectors and GLM matrices for storing the vertices and normals but as you know neither of those abstractions are available for C, and I would rather not use C++ because I do not know C++ and C++ isn't just "C with classes" anymore, so I'd be misusing it.

I know there are probably libraries for C that provide similar functionality to vectors and matrices, but I'm trying to gain a concrete knowledge of how the model loading is actually done and I can't seem to understand all of the C++ floating around on the internet (again, I'm not very familiar with it).

So what I want to know is, what are the steps to loading a model into OpenGL from a C perspective?

Comment: So your problem is not with changing a vector to an array (which is simple) but with using `glm::vec3` and the like in C?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right, in fact, I do have a simple dynamic array structure using malloc etc, but I can't figure out how to reproduce the GLM vectors and matrices.
Also if somebody could explain what exactly these things get populated with I'd appreciate it.

Comment: OpenGL doesn't really care what the container is, as long as it is sequential. IIRC you actually pass a mere pointer to the GL server along with the size in order to copy that data to GPU ram.

Comment: It doesn't look like GLM can be used from C as it is a C++ "header only" library.

Comment: my favorite http://syoyo.github.io/tinyobjloader/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing in OpenGL requiring C++. OpenGL itself is designed as a C API. People use mostly C++ because it is faster to develop in it.

OpenGL doesn't really care what container the data is in, whether it is a C++ vector, a vanilla, on-the-stack C array or a memory pool allocated with `malloc`. The majority of GL functions that involve transfer of data to the GPU take in a pointer to the first element and a size variable to indicate how long it is.

The same applies to matrices and multi-component vectors (different from C++ std::vector) - as long as the data is appropriately aligned you are good to go.

Here is an example taken out of the QVector4D class which works perfectly with OpenGL. A quick peek at its "private parts" reveals there is nothing to it:

```
private:
    float xp, yp, zp, wp;
```

That's all it is, 4 floats side by side. Take a look at a 4x4 matrix class - no rocket science either:

```
private:
    float m[4][4];          // Column-major order to match OpenGL.
```

So, you can perfectly well use OpenGL with C, the GL functions are the same, the only thing that changes is you will be working with "C idioms" rather than C++.

EDIT: For a basic "hello triangle" or something really simple, you could just use a C array on the stack. But 3D models may actually pack quite a lot of vertices, plus there is no way for you to know in advance how many, which makes stack arrays not applicable - the geometry may exceed the stack and lead to... well... stack overflow and crash, plus the array size must be known at compile time.

So, what you should be doing is allocate memory dynamically with `malloc(vertCount * sizeof(float)`, as much as you need for the particular mesh, load the floats from the mesh in and use that "array" to pass to OpenGL functions. If you haven't used dynamic memory don't worry, just look it up, it is (almost) the same as working with a stack array, with the caution note that you have to `free()` that memory manually otherwise it will leak.

You shouldn't have too much trouble with importing OBJ, it is an open and rather simple format. But parsing it is a whole different topic.

Comment: This helps me a lot, I wish I could vote it up.
So basically I could render the model in roughly the same way that I would render a cube or triangle save for the fact that in the case of the former I have to load in the file and the fact that I have far more data to store into whatever type I am using?

Usually for the vertices I would just have an array of GLfloats for the coordinates, like I have in this function http://lpaste.net/103127.

I guess I should learn a little more about the obj file format to get a sense of what I will need to store and how to store it.


Am I getting this right?

Comment: Learning endeavors aside, as much as I love C and reinventing the wheel, long term I'd recommend you focus on some library that provides out of the box functionality. And don't worry, C++ ain't that bad...well, in a way it is madness, but you could do with a very basic subset of it very similar to C and still get substantial development time improvements.

Comment: @Red: I'm maintaining a pure C99 static inline header library for doing the linear math: http://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h

Comment: @datenwolf - even if not used directly, very illustrative and educational on the subject

Comment: Thanks you guys.
@datenwolf I think I've seen you on /g/ where I made a thread about this same thing, very nice repo thanks a bunch.